# Parse string in C# using regex and replace

Tags: c#, regex

I have to parse string in C# as:

> Some text [ first_name | User ] some other text. [ Your birthday is on yy/mm/dd | ]

Example:

> Dear [ first_name | User ], How are you?. [ Your birthday is on yy/mm/dd | ]

So, I check for brackets `[]` in whole text, remove space before and after characters: `[`, `|`, `]` and fill the `first_name` from database and if `first_name` is not available then replace with alternative text which is `User` in this case.

And if there is no birthday present in database then replace `Your birthday is on yy/mm/dd` with `null`.

I know regex is for string matching, but how do I do string replacement like: `Replace("first_name", Name);` in regex?

Is there a third party librabry for this?

Comment: This is too complex for regex. It is doable, but not worth the time and trouble. You should consider using a template engine like [RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex can do this :) Please try something like that :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var processedText = Regex.Replace("Some text [first_name | User] some other text. [Your birthday is on yy / mm / dd | ]. " +
            "Dear [ first_name | User ], How are you?. [ Your birthday is on yy/mm/dd | ]",
            @"\[\s*(.*?)\s*\|\s*(.*?)\s*\]", new MatchEvaluator(ReplaceAction));

        Console.WriteLine(processedText);
    }

    public static bool DummyTryGetValueFromDb(string key, out string value)
    {
        Random randomizer = new Random(DateTime.UtcNow.Millisecond);

        if (randomizer.Next(100) > 50) // Successfully found in db :)
        {
            if (key == "first_name")
            {
                value = "Toto";
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                value = "Your birthday is on your birthday date from db !";
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            value = string.Empty;
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static string ReplaceAction(Match match)
    {
        if (match.Groups.Count > 1)
        {
            var dataKeyGroup = match.Groups[1];
            if (DummyTryGetValueFromDb(dataKeyGroup.Value, out var valueFromDb))
                return valueFromDb;
            else if (match.Groups.Count > 2)
                return match.Groups[2].Value;
            else
                return "[Not found from db, no alternative value]"; // you can throw exception
        }
        else
            return "[Bad syntax]"; // you can throw exception
    }
}
```

Comment: You just hard-coded a solution for `"[Your birthday is on yy / mm / dd | ]"`. Although OP's example isnt the best.

Comment: You're right : the main thing is that the structure answers the question, the details of data access and date conversion are still to be considered.

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex.Replace("Dear [ first_name | User ], How are you?. [ Your birthday is on yy/mm/dd | ]", "Your Pattern", firstName ?? User)
```